# (assoc element alist) get all the entities autolisp

Tags: autolisp

I've googled for it for a while but I didn't find the solution.

I've this list:

```
((-1 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ff905910>) (0 . "DICTIONARY") (5 . "1F9") (102 . "{ACAD_REACTORS") (330 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ff9038c0>) (102 . "}") (330 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ff9038c0>) (100 . "AcDbDictionary") (280 . 0) (281 . 1) (3 . "1") (350 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ff9933c0>) (3 . "2") (350 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ff9fa0d0>) (3 . "3") (350 . <Nome entità: 7ff5ff9fa410>))
```

I want to get all the entities with dxf code 350.
With that instruction I can get only the fist one.

```
(assoc 350 list)
```

How to get all the associations?

Thanks, Dennis

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to achieve this - here are a few examples:

```
(defun mAssoc1 ( key lst / rtn )
    (foreach x lst
        (if (= key (car x))
            (setq rtn (cons (cdr x) rtn))
        )
    )
    (reverse rtn)
)

(defun mAssoc2 ( key lst )
    (apply 'append
        (mapcar
            (function
                (lambda ( x ) (if (= key (car x)) (list (cdr x))))
            )
            lst
        )
    )
)


(defun mAssoc3 ( key lst )
    (mapcar 'cdr
        (vl-remove-if-not
            (function (lambda ( x ) (= key (car x))))
            lst
        )
    )
)


(defun mAssoc4 ( key lst / item )
    (if (setq item (assoc key lst))
        (cons (cdr item) (mAssoc4 key (cdr (member item lst))))
    )
)


(defun mAssoc5 ( key lst / item rtn )
    (while (setq item (assoc key lst))
        (setq rtn (cons (cdr item) rtn) lst (cdr (member item lst)))
    )
    (reverse rtn)
)


(defun mAssoc6 ( key lst )
    (mapcar 'cdr (acet-list-m-assoc key lst))
)


(defun mAssoc7 ( key lst )
    (if lst
        (if (= key (caar lst))
            (cons (cdar lst) (mAssoc7 key (cdr lst)))
            (mAssoc7 key (cdr lst))
        )
    )
)
```

Here is a quick performance comparison for the above functions:

```
;;; Benchmarking: Elapsed milliseconds / relative speed for 32768 iteration(s):
;;;
;;;    (MASSOC4 2 L).....1482 / 1.25 <fastest>
;;;    (MASSOC5 2 L).....1482 / 1.25
;;;    (MASSOC6 2 L).....1498 / 1.24
;;;    (MASSOC3 2 L).....1638 / 1.13
;;;    (MASSOC7 2 L).....1747 / 1.06
;;;    (MASSOC1 2 L).....1748 / 1.06
;;;    (MASSOC2 2 L).....1856 / 1 <slowest>
```

Answer (score 0):

assoc returns only first one, so You need to loop by all after find one as long as none is found `(assoc returns nil)`. You should try such code:

```
(defun DXF:Dump (EntDef code / out)
    (while (setq values(assoc code EntDef))
        (setq out (append out (list (cdr values))))
        (setq EntDef(cdr(member values EntDef)))
    )
    out
)

; (setq dxfs (entget (car (entsel))))

; (DXF:Dump dxfs 350)
```